# How to wait until get a specific response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, I want to upload a file and wait until I get the response "processStatus = Published". For that, I have added JSON Extractor and passed $.A.B.processStatus to get the desired variable from the response. Next thing I have added a while controller and tried to write groovy script but not sure how to write groovy script to wait until processStatus = Published. Please can someone help and correct the syntax? Thanks

```
{
   "A":{
      "B":[
         {
            "fileName":"068812_C00.jpg",
            "activated":true,               
            "fileSize":359894,
            "importTime":"2023-05-26T07:06:58.174Z",
            "fileType":"Picture",        
            "processStatus":"Published",
            "fileExt":"jpg",      
         }
      ],
      "amount":1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function syntax would be something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('variable-from-JSON-extractor-here') != 'Published' ,)}
```

in the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in the scope of the current thread (virtual user). See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)  article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When the API runs, the response doesn't show "processStatus" and it only appears when it becomes published. So the first response doesn't contain processStatus. Should it still work this way? It is not entering in the loop.
Secondly, how can I find that I am getting the correct variable in the JSON extractor?

Comment: It will enter the loop because it will evaluate to `false` only when the variable will have `Published` value. You can set initial value using i.e. [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) if you want  I would rather worry that it will enter into an endless loop. You can check extracted variable presence/value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

Comment: It is stuck in the infinite loop and uploading an image. I think it is because it is unable to find the processStatus. How can I stop it to stuck in infinite loop and wait until it finds processStatus in the JSON response.

Comment: You need to amend your JSON Path expression to `A.B[0].processStatus` or just to `$..processStatus` as B is a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) hence you need to specify either index or wildcard or use [deep scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators). More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: Thanks, I got it. The problem I see is it is create request (201) that is adding a new ID. Is there a way to stop creating a new request so it doesn't create a new one and wait for the same create request to show the processStatus?

Comment: I am able to get the required response in the JSON extractor but the loop is not ending.
This command is not running, not sure what is wrong with this?
${__groovy(vars.get('processStatus') != "Published" ,)}